# Prove convexity of a function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a task as in the quote block. By checking the Hessian matrices of $f(x,y)$'s. I found Hessian's of a) b) are not semidefinite, and c) is. Explicitly $H=$

a) \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

b) \begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{x^2\ln10} & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{y^2\ln10} 
\end{pmatrix}

c) \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

so I concluded that only c) is a convex function. My question is why the domain $\left\{(x, y) \in R^{2} |x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 4\right\}$ given in the question makes no impact. Did I miss something, or my answer is wrong?

> Which of the following functions is convex? Prove your answers
>   directly by verifying the definition, by applying theorems discussed
>   in class or by discussing a counter example. Make sure you check all
>   the parts of the definition.
>
> a) $f:\left\{(x, y) \in R^{2} |x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 4\right\} \rightarrow R, f(x, y)=x y$
>
> b) $f:\left\{(x, y) \in R^{2} | x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 4\right\} \rightarrow R, f(x, y)=\log _{10}(x y)$
>
> c) $f:\left\{(x, y) \in R^{2} | x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 4\right\} \rightarrow R, f(x, y)=\log _{10}\left(e^{x} e^{y}\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in (b), the domain is incorrect: $\log_{10}(xy)$ is not a real number if $xy \le 0$.

But the domain (when it is correct) has no impact here because the Hessian is or is not positive semidefinite on the whole domain.  If you had a function such as $x^3 + y^2$, whose 
Hessian matrix is $\pmatrix{6x & 0\cr 0 & 2\cr}$, that matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if $x \ge 0$.  Then the function is convex on a domain in which $x \ge 0$ always,
but not if the domain contains points with $x < 0$.

Comment: "the domain is incorrect" is overly conclusive, perhaps the error is in the function formula

Comment: @LinAlg OK.  The domain is not a correct domain for the function as given.  If it's a different function, all bets are off.

Comment: You seem to have a misunderstanding of what a function is. A domain is as much part of the definition of a function as the formula. If it's a different domain, all bets are off as well.

Comment: I assure you I understand what a function is.  Of course I should have said "a different formula".